# Failure to remove Libreoffice 7 on Ubuntu 20 after update of Libreoffice

Tags: 20.04, updates, launcher, libreoffice

Ubuntu updater has updated the whole libreoffice suite. I also installed Java 16 on Ubuntu 20.04 and set it as JRE in Libreoffice. Now, Libreoffice does not start at all and if I try to remove it I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Not using locking for read-only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read-only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to mkstemp /tmp/clearsigned.message.0NkBl2 - GetTempFile (30: Read-only file system)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Why the error? How can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Ubuntu 20? Can you be more specific? Is that now your current version? From what version did you upgrade? How did you install java? Probably, it would have been better to reset the java engine to default before doing the upgrade.

Comment: I am using U. 20.04. Libreoffice was updated from 7.1.2.2 to 7.1.3.2.

Comment: You have broken filesystem! FIx the `Read-only file system` first!